# Cloud function not found from SDK but callable via HTTPS

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've deployed some cloud functions to my Firebase project. If I call them with a REST client (such as Postman) they work fine. I'm able to execute them and the output is just as expected.

However, I've tried calling them with both de Web SDK and the Android SDK and, in both cases, I'm getting a `not-found` error. For example, I tried calling my function `createRoom` with the following code (btw, quite similar to the official docs example):

```
var firebase = require("firebase/app");

require("firebase/functions");


let firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "...",
  authDomain: "...",
  databaseURL: "...",
  projectId: "...",
  storageBucket: "...",
  messagingSenderId: "...",
  appId: "...",
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

var cloudFunctions = firebase.functions();

const createRoom = cloudFunctions.httpsCallable("createRoom");
createRoom()
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

and I keep getting following error:

```
HttpsErrorImpl: not-found
    at new HttpsErrorImpl (/home/pitazzo/Proyectos/maximiliana/firebase-mock/node_modules/@firebase/functions/dist/index.node.cjs.js:62:28)
    at _errorForResponse (/home/pitazzo/Proyectos/maximiliana/firebase-mock/node_modules/@firebase/functions/dist/index.node.cjs.js:157:12)
    at Service.<anonymous> (/home/pitazzo/Proyectos/maximiliana/firebase-mock/node_modules/@firebase/functions/dist/index.node.cjs.js:574:33)
    at step (/home/pitazzo/Proyectos/maximiliana/firebase-mock/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:141:27)
    at Object.next (/home/pitazzo/Proyectos/maximiliana/firebase-mock/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:122:57)
    at fulfilled (/home/pitazzo/Proyectos/maximiliana/firebase-mock/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:112:62)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  code: 'not-found',
  details: undefined
}
```

Using the Android SDK I get an equivalent error, also including the `not-found` error code. I can't see whats wrong, because calling the function directly works perfectly.
FYI, calls executed with the SDKs are not event registered in the Firebase console logs. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code of the function you're trying to invoke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem: Cloud Functions are only avaible in those regions where them were deployed.

That means, you have to specify the region where you want to execute the function when calling it. If no region is specified, Firebase looks for it in `us-central-1`. If it can not be found there, it fails.